# Insert rows to 1:1 related tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, shared-primary-key

I want to put new rows into tables related 1:1 in `sql-server`. 
[image: diagram of those tables]

As you see, tables reference each other with the same primary key. And here is the problem- I know that putting data with two `INSERT` calls will throw me an error saying I violate PK constraint. Is there a way of doing this in-code? I want to create a stored procedure used for adding "primary products" (SUROWCE) and corresponding to it record in "stock" (STAN).

My code attempt: 
`INSERT INTO STAN VALUES(25, 5, 1000);
INSERT INTO SUROWCE VALUES(25, 'wood');`

`Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_STAN_SUROWCE". The conflict occurred in database "TestBazyDanych", table "dbo.SUROWCE", column 'ID_SUROWCA'.`

Comment: Sounds like you want an [`AFTER INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) trigger.

Comment: From the tables you posted having two tables here seems unnecessary. The second table is nothing more than a single nvarchar(50) in STAN. Why make it more complicated than it needs to be? Sure there are times where a separate table makes sense but this doesn't seem to be one of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a 1:1 relationship, only one table has a Foreign Key referencing the other.  So you insert into the table *without* the foreign key first.  Try simply reversing the order of the inserts:

```
INSERT INTO SUROWCE VALUES(25, 'wood');
INSERT INTO STAN VALUES(25, 5, 1000);
```

Comment: And, as usual, the two inserts should be wrapped in a transaction if you want to ensure that either both succeed or neither succeeds.